# MediaPlayer stages c#

Tags: file, workflow, media-player

I am creating a mediaPlayer instance that opens a wav file, plays it, and when finished (I know it finishes by Media_ended event) opens a different wav file and precised continuously.

In the middle of this process a user event can occur. This event stops the mediaPlayer, closes it and sets a new source for the mediaPlayer.

I want to reuse the wav files in the system. That means that after I close the mediaPlayer I change the wav file. 
Sometimes I encounter a problem when trying to change the wav file that was set as the source of the mediaPlayer by mediaPlayer.Open() when the Media_Opened event didn't fire.

From my understanding of mediaPlayer, the open occurs in a different thread. The user event which is in higher priority stops the opening process. Sometimes the opening process is stopped in the middle, in a stage that the file is open but the process didn't complete such that close releases the file.

Do I understand correctly the flow?

How can I insure the release of file? Or how can I make sure that the file opens properly before closing?

Comment: Another alternative, how can I access the thread that handles the opening of the mediaPlayer? Accessing this thread can help me finish opening the mediaPlayer before closing it by using 'Join'.

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I have the same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18156870/open-mediaplayer-event-unhandled-in-thread

Comment: In order to avoid closing a media player that didn't open, I worked with events and semaphores. I waited for the player to open and then I closed it.